# Using Product standard price in Custom Object

Tags: lookup, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

I'm trying to create a classic Invoice by using Custom Object

- `Invoice` (Master)
- `Invoice Line Item` (Detail)

`Invoice_Line_Item` should have a look up relationship with `Product`. Also it has to include `Quantity`, `Total` (formula) and `Unit Price` (the selected **product standard price**).

I've trying using formula and look up type for unit price. But I wasn't able to referral that Product property.

### Question:

There exist any way to use Product standard price in a custom object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit Price, unless a custom field, is not a field available on the Product object. In order to achieve what I think you are after I think you would have to revert to code either as part of a custom controller or a trigger.

I think you would need to query the PricebookEntry object:

```
   Select p.UnitPrice, p.Product2.Name, p.Product2.Id, p.Product2Id, 
   p.Pricebook2.IsStandard, p.Pricebook2Id From PricebookEntry p
   where p.Pricebook2.IsStandard = true
   and p.Product2Id = :someProductId
```

Unfortunately, you can't create a lookup directly to PricebookEntry as it's one of those 'funny' objects.

Comment: Thanks, I liked your expression "those funny objects". A trigger was my choice.

Comment: I believe its the technical term ;)